# What can't I UPDATE my table with PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to update a MySQL table with some simple PHP, but every time I run this command, I get my error message: "Site is offline, please check back later!" The string I'm inputting is only one simple paragraph but it's got some HTML code in it. What kind of sanitizing is it going to take to get this thing to work? Here's the code:

```
if (!empty($_POST) && $_SESSION['logged'] == 1)
{
    $title = $_POST['title1'];
    $body = $_POST['body1'];
    $query = "UPDATE pages SET title = '$title', body = '$body' WHERE id = '$id'";
    $do_query = mysql_query($query) or die ("Site is offline, please check back later!");
}
```

And the paragraph I'm trying to update with:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br /><br />Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. <br /><br />Please visit <a href="http://lipsum.com">Lipsum's website</a> for more info.
```

Comment: You're not escaping your text, so your SQL is wrong after `industry`

Comment: You're very open to SQL injection. `title1=&body1=&id=' OR 1 = 1` would screw up ALL your pages. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @popnoodles Seems to be, yeah. This is the exact reason "it's only going to be used as an internal system" is the worst reasoning in the world to not escape SQL variables.

Comment: Do `echo $query;`, copy the output and try to run the query manually, using phpMyAdmin or similar. Solution: switch to MySQLi/PDO and start using prepared statements.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes I understand, this page is very open to what I can insert simply due to the fact that I am the only one using it and the only one that has access to it. It's just some old code I'm playing around with

Comment: If you're somehow stuck with `mysql_` functions, you can use `mysql_real_escape_string($query);` before executing it, but I *strongly* recommend you switch immediately. Time to stop using deprecated stuff.

Comment: @user3061610 But **because** of this problem and you not escaping your variables, you are getting this error. There's no excuse to ever be picking the easier path with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your question, your SQL query is failing because the text you're inserting contains a single-quote, `'`, and you're not escaping it.

To fix this, you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to sanitize your data:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title1']);
$body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body1']);
```

However, I would highly recommend you take the time now to *stop* using the older `mysql_` functions and switch to a more-supported [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) library; these will allow you to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent this issue altogether.

An example with MySQLi:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE pages SET title = ?, body = ? WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['title1']);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['body1']);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my issue. And thanks everyone else for the answers.